# Can concurrent objects with same consensus number implement each other?

Tags: concurrency, theory, consensus

My question is a bit theoretical.

First, we have definitions of concurrent objects and consensus hierarchy. Consensus hierarchy classifies concurrent objects with consensus number.

But I want to ask whether objects with the same consensus number can implement each other. In fact I know the answer is false. But can you give some examples, or does this imply some finer structure in the consensus hierarchy?

Comment: It might help if you define your terms a little bit, or at least link to the relevant wikipedia entries that explain them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a universal algorithm that takes n-consensus objects and uses them to implement a wait-free n-threaded version of any serially-specified object (in particular, your other object).

So, since by definition if an object has consensus number n then it can implement a wait-free n-threaded consensus object, it can vicariously (using the aforementioned algorithm) implement a wait-free n-threaded version of your other object.

How do you know that the answer is false? If it truly is then there's something wrong with my reasoning here.

EDIT: After reading more, the implementation is limited to n threads. For any number of threads  it's an open question (Or so my Multicore Programming TA says). No one knows if they can implement each other.